# I want to install node js while python is already installed

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, installation

I have already installed python in my laptop, when I tried to install node js, it installed python again so it changed my python environment variables, now I had to uninstall python and reinstall it to work as it was working before.

I want to reinstall node js, what should I keep in mind so it does not touch python?

Comment: Installing node shouldn't mess with your Python env variables

Comment: When installing Node.js, it shouldn't interfere with your existing Python installation if you use the default settings

Comment: i think you are using windows, then you can download both installers from their websites and install one and open your path environment variables settings and check the path strings and then install another installer then again check the env variables is there any collision